# Are permutation group block only defined in the context of finite sets?

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-actions

From Dummit and Foote (emphasis mine):

> Let $G$ be a transitive permutation group on the **finite** set $A$. A block is a nonempty subset $B$ of $A$ s.t. $\forall \sigma\in G:$ either $\sigma(B)\cap B = B$ or $\sigma(B)\cap B = \emptyset$.

However from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28permutation_group_theory%29) I can infer no constraint on the cardinality of $A$.

This question stems from the following proof attempt:

> Prove that a doubly transitive group is primitive.

Let $B$ be a block in $A$. Consider $a\in B$, and take $b\in B-\{a\}$, $c\not\in B$. Then by double transitivity there is $\sigma\in G_a$ s.t. $c=\sigma b$. *Now if $A$, and thus also $B$, is finite, we can conclude that $\sigma(B)\cap B$ cannot equal $B$ by a pigeon-hole style argument. Hence $\sigma(B)\cap B=\emptyset$*.

Since $\sigma a= a$, we must have $\sigma(B)\cap B = B$.

This would now be a contradiction, so either we cannot choose $b\in B-\{a\}$ or we cannot choose $c\not\in B$, thus either $B=\{a\}$ or $B=A.\blacksquare$

The problem with the proof is indicated by the italic text, and this problem inspired my question about the definition of a block. I know of another proof that does work (I believe regardless of the cardinalities) but I'm still curious about the definition of a block.

I'm also curious if my proof is salvageable even if $B$ is infinite, since in that case I don't see how we can proof $\sigma(B)\cap B$ cannot equal $B$.

Comment: You don't need to assume finiteness. Clearly $\sigma(B) \cap B \ne \sigma(B)$, hence $B \cap \sigma^{-1}(B) \ne B$ but $a \in B \cap \sigma^{-1}(B)$ so we get a contradiction.

Comment: @DerekHolt Nice! thanks, for some reason I didn't see that. Do you also have an idea about the definition of a block?

Comment: @user2520938 There's nothing wrong with extending or otherwise modifying a *definition* to your needs. However, you need to be careful if you want to use any *theorems* based on the original definition. That being said, instead of taking a block you might simply consider  the *orbit* of $a$

Comment: The definition of a block is valid also for infinite sets. The theorem that a transitive group $G$ is primitive if and only $G_\alpha$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ also does not depend on finiteness.

Comment: @DerekHolt I realise that one can define a block also for infinite sets, but what I mean is whether or not the D&F definition mentioning only finite sets is the 'standard' definition, or if the more general wikipedia definition is the standard definition.

Comment: I would say that the wikipedia definition is standard, but since $\sigma$ is a bijection, $\sigma(B) \cap B = B$ is equivalent to $\sigma(B)=B$, so the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't think these are equivalent if $A$ is infinite. $\sigma(B) \cap B = B$ does imply $B\subset \sigma(B)$, but since infinite sets can be in bijection with subsets of themselves, I don't see how equality follows. Take $B$ all even numbers, and let $\sigma(n)=\frac{n}{2}$. Then $\sigma(B) \cap B = B$, but clearly not  $B= \sigma(B)$.

Comment: Yes sorry what I wrote was misleading. What I meant was that the two definitions of a block are equivalent, because $B \subset \sigma(B) \Rightarrow \sigma^{-1}(B) \subset B \Rightarrow B \cap \sigma^{-1}(B) \ne \emptyset \Rightarrow B \subset \sigma^{-1}(B) \Rightarrow \sigma(B) \subset B$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, it's all clear now. Still find it annoying that D&F suggests that blocks are somehow only defined/considered in the context of finite sets $A$, while there doesn't seem to be any reason for this.